# IAM Policy to only allow requests coming through ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking to implement an IAM policy for the following scenario:

```
 ┌──────────────┐
 │   Internet   │─ ┐
 └──────────────┘
         │         │
         │
         ▼         │
 ┌──────────────┐
 │     AlB      │  │
 └──────────────┘
         │         │
         │
┌────────┼───────┐ │
│ECS     ▼       │
│┌──────────────┐│ │
││     Task     ││
│└──────────────┘│ │
│        │       │
└────────┼───────┘ │
         │
         ▼         │
 ┌──────────────┐
 │    API GW    │◀ ┘
 └──────────────┘
```

I want to prevent users from accessing the API gateway directly. I want to create an IAM policy on the API gateway that will only accept requests coming via an ECS task. I was thinking of using the `calledVia` context key but this only seems to support a small list of services but not ECS.

Comment: `CalledVia` is for very different conditions. The tasks run with a specific IAM role you specify. You can restrict access to only that role.

Comment: Why not just restrict the API gateway to your VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html